# Memory leak with CIColor spritekit

Tags: memory-leaks, sprite-kit, instruments

I created a class that would generate a hud item, this hud item can animate the resulting texture which is a gradient created using cicolor that is then saved into a uiimage which is in turn used for an sktexture. I've noticed now that i am getting a lot of memory growth in my app and running it through instruments has shown me this, but i can't for the life figure out whats going on:

Here's the error i get[image]
You can't really see the issue so it's giving me 91.4% on this line of code:

```
animatedGraphic = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithTexture:[[TextureList sharedManager]returnGradientofSize:[[TextureList sharedManager]returnTextureSize:kGMHUDFlowerTarget] topColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:121.0/255.0] bottomColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:225.0/255.0 green:57.0/255.0 blue:86.0/255.0]] color:[UIColor orangeColor] size:CGSizeMake(0, self.frame.size.height)];
            animatedGraphic.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
            animatedGraphic.zPosition = self.zPosition+1;
            [self addChild:animatedGraphic];
```

Heres the code for the sktexture with a gradient:

```
-(SKTexture*)returnHorizontalGradientofSize:(CGSize)size
                                  leftColor:(CIColor*)leftColor
                                 rightColor:(CIColor*)rightColor{

    CIContext *coreImageContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIFilter *gradientFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILinearGradient"];
    [gradientFilter setDefaults];
    CIVector *startVector = [CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:size.height/2];
    CIVector *endVector = [CIVector vectorWithX:size.width Y:size.height/2];
    [gradientFilter setValue:startVector forKey:@"inputPoint0"];
    [gradientFilter setValue:endVector forKey:@"inputPoint1"];
    [gradientFilter setValue:leftColor forKey:@"inputColor0"];
    [gradientFilter setValue:rightColor forKey:@"inputColor1"];
    CGImageRef cgimg = [coreImageContext createCGImage:[gradientFilter outputImage]
                                              fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CFRelease(cgimg);
    return [SKTexture textureWithImage:theImage];
}
```

Heres the code for the hud item:

```
#import "ItemHud.h"
#import "TextureList.h"
#import "UnlockController.h"

@interface ItemHud ()

@property (nonatomic) double scoreIncrement;
@property (nonatomic) double increment;
@property (nonatomic) double barIncrement;
@property (nonatomic) double updateIncrement;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL barAnimating;
@end

@implementation ItemHud

@synthesize theLabel;
@synthesize theLabelTwo;
@synthesize animatedGraphic;
@synthesize iconGraphic;


-(id)initWithImageNamed:(NSString *)ImageName
              withLabel:(NSString *)LabelName
           withLabelTwo:(NSString *)LabelNameTwo
        withIconGraphic:(NSString *)iconGraphicName
    withAnimatedGraphic:(BOOL)AnimatedGraphicName{

    if (self = [super init]) {

        if (ImageName)
        {
            self.size = [[TextureList sharedManager]returnTextureSize:ImageName];
            self.texture = nil;
            self.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.65];
            self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            _barAnimating = NO;

        }
        if (AnimatedGraphicName) {
            animatedGraphic = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithTexture:[[TextureList sharedManager]returnGradientofSize:[[TextureList sharedManager]returnTextureSize:kGMHUDFlowerTarget] topColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:121.0/255.0] bottomColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:225.0/255.0 green:57.0/255.0 blue:86.0/255.0]] color:[UIColor orangeColor] size:CGSizeMake(0, self.frame.size.height)];
            animatedGraphic.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
            animatedGraphic.zPosition = self.zPosition+1;
            [self addChild:animatedGraphic];

        }
        if (iconGraphicName) {
            if ([iconGraphicName isEqualToString:kGMHUDLevelIcon1] || [iconGraphicName isEqualToString:kGMHUDLevelIcon2] || [iconGraphicName isEqualToString:kGMHUDLevelIcon3] || [iconGraphicName isEqualToString:kGMHUDLevelIcon4]|| [iconGraphicName isEqualToString:kGMHUDLevelIcon5] || [iconGraphicName isEqualToString:kGMHUDLevelIcon6] || [iconGraphicName isEqualToString:kGMHUDLevelIcon7] || [iconGraphicName isEqualToString:kGMHUDLevelIcon8] || [iconGraphicName isEqualToString:kGMHUDLevelIcon9]) {
                iconGraphic = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:iconGraphicName] color:nil size:[[TextureList sharedManager]returnTextureSize:kGMHUDLevelIcon1]];
            }
            else{
               iconGraphic = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:iconGraphicName] color:nil size:[[TextureList sharedManager]returnTextureSize:iconGraphicName]];
            }
            iconGraphic.zPosition = self.zPosition+1;
            [self addChild:iconGraphic];
            [self setGraphicRight:NO];
        }
        if (LabelName) {
            theLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:kFontName];
            [theLabel setFontColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [theLabel setFontName:kFontName];
            [theLabel setFontSize:kFontSizeMDMedium];
            [theLabel setHorizontalAlignmentMode:SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft];
            [theLabel setVerticalAlignmentMode:SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter];
            theLabel.text = LabelName;
            [self addChild:theLabel];
            [self setHudDefaults:YES];
        }
        if (LabelNameTwo) {
            theLabelTwo = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:kFontName];
            [theLabelTwo setFontColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [theLabelTwo setFontName:kFontName];
            [theLabelTwo setFontSize:kFontSizeMDMedium];
            [theLabelTwo setHorizontalAlignmentMode:SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeRight];
            [theLabelTwo setVerticalAlignmentMode:SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter];
            theLabelTwo.text = LabelNameTwo;
            [self addChild:theLabelTwo];
            [self setHudDefaults:NO];
        }

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setBackgroundImage:(SKTexture*)theTexture{

    self.texture = theTexture;
}

-(void)setHudDefaults:(BOOL)singleLabel{

    theLabelTwo.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x+self.frame.size.width/2,self.position.y);
    animatedGraphic.position = CGPointMake(-self.frame.size.width/2,self.position.y);

    if (singleLabel) {
        [theLabel setHorizontalAlignmentMode:SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter];
        theLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x,self.position.y);
    }
    else{
        theLabel.position = CGPointMake(theLabelTwo.position.x-theLabelTwo.frame.size.width/2-20,self.position.y);
        [theLabel setHorizontalAlignmentMode:SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeRight];
    }

    theLabel.zPosition = self.zPosition+1;
    theLabelTwo.zPosition = self.zPosition+1;

}

-(void)setGraphicRight:(BOOL)placeRight{

    if (placeRight) {
        iconGraphic.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,-self.frame.size.height/4);
        iconGraphic.zPosition = animatedGraphic.zPosition+1;
    }
    else{
        iconGraphic.position = CGPointMake(-self.frame.size.width/2,-self.frame.size.height/4);
        iconGraphic.zPosition = animatedGraphic.zPosition+1;
    }
}

-(void)setBarProgress:(int)flowerTarget currentFlowers:(int)currentFlowers{

    double increment = (double)flowerTarget/100;
    //NSLog(@"increment is %f",increment);
    double barIncrement = (double)self.frame.size.width/100;
    //NSLog(@"BAR increment is %f",barIncrement);
    double barState = (barIncrement/increment)*currentFlowers;
    //NSLog(@"BAR state is %f",barState);

    /*if (animatedGraphic.frame.size.width >= self.frame.size.width && !_barAnimating) {
        _barAnimating = YES;
        [self animateBar:YES];
    }
    else if (animatedGraphic.frame.size.width < self.frame.size.width && _barAnimating){
        _barAnimating = NO;
        [self animateBar:NO];
    }*/

    animatedGraphic.size = CGSizeMake(barState, self.frame.size.height);

}

-(void)setBarValues:(int)startValue increment:(int)increment nextObject:(int)nextObject{

    //NSLog(@"0:Totalscore is %i",[[UserDetails sharedManager]userTotalScore]);
    //NSLog(@"1:StartValue %i",startValue);
    //NSLog(@"2:Increment %i",increment);
    //NSLog(@"3:Nextobject %i",nextObject);

    _scoreIncrement = (double)startValue/(double)nextObject;
    //NSLog(@"increment is %f",increment);

    _barIncrement = (double)self.frame.size.width/100;
    //NSLog(@"bar increment is %f",barIncrement);

    _updateIncrement = ((double)startValue/_scoreIncrement)/100;
    //NSLog(@"update increment is %f",updateIncrement);

    //NSLog(@"4:Animate %f",_barIncrement/_updateIncrement*increment);
    animatedGraphic.size = CGSizeMake(_barIncrement/_updateIncrement*increment, self.frame.size.height);

}
-(void)updateBarProgress:(int)update{

    animatedGraphic.size = CGSizeMake(_barIncrement/_updateIncrement*update, self.frame.size.height);
    //hudFx.position = CGPointMake(animatedGraphic.frame.size.width-2, animatedGraphic.position.y);

}

-(void)setBarValues:(int)startValue nextObject:(int)nextObject animated:(BOOL)animated{

    // start value is difference between unlock score and current value
    // next object is score to unlock item

    // all unlocks done
    if ([[UnlockController sharedManager]allunlocksOpen]) {
        theLabel.text = @"ALL ITEMS UNLOCKED";
        return;
    }

    __block int count = 0;

    double increment = (double)startValue/(double)nextObject;
    //NSLog(@"increment is %f",increment);

    double countUp = nextObject-startValue;
    //NSLog(@"countup is %f",countUp);

    double barIncrement = (double)self.frame.size.width/100;
    //NSLog(@"bar increment is %f",barIncrement);

    double updateIncrement = ((double)startValue/increment)/100;
    //NSLog(@"update increment is %f",updateIncrement);

    if (!animated) {
        animatedGraphic.size = CGSizeMake(barIncrement/updateIncrement*startValue, self.frame.size.height);
        //hudFx.position = CGPointMake(animatedGraphic.frame.size.width-2, animatedGraphic.position.y);
    }
    else{

        SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.0];
        SKAction *animateCount = [SKAction runBlock:^{
            count++;
            animatedGraphic.size = CGSizeMake(barIncrement*count, self.frame.size.height);
            //hudFx.position = CGPointMake(animatedGraphic.frame.size.width-2, animatedGraphic.position.y);

        }];
        SKAction *animateSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[animateCount,delay]];
        SKAction *repeatSequence = [SKAction repeatAction:animateSequence count:(double)countUp/updateIncrement];

        [animatedGraphic runAction:repeatSequence completion:^{

        }];
    }
}

-(void)animateBar:(BOOL)animate{

    SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.15];

    SKAction *changeToAnimateBar = [SKAction runBlock:^{

        animatedGraphic.texture = [[TextureList sharedManager]returnGradientofSize:[[TextureList sharedManager]returnTextureSize:kGMHUDFlowerTarget] topColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:244.0/255.0 blue:155.0/255.0] bottomColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:225.0/255.0 green:57.0/255.0 blue:86.0/255.0]];
    }];
    SKAction *changeToDefaultBar = [SKAction runBlock:^{

        animatedGraphic.texture = [[TextureList sharedManager]returnGradientofSize:[[TextureList sharedManager]returnTextureSize:kGMHUDFlowerTarget] topColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:121.0/255.0] bottomColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:225.0/255.0 green:57.0/255.0 blue:86.0/255.0]];
    }];

    SKAction *animateSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[changeToAnimateBar,delay,changeToDefaultBar,delay]];
    SKAction *animatingBarLoop = [SKAction repeatActionForever:animateSequence];

    if (animate) {
        [self runAction:animatingBarLoop withKey:@"animatingBar"];
    }
    else{
        [self removeActionForKey:@"animatingBar"];
        [self runAction:changeToDefaultBar withKey:@"defaultBar"];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a memory leak, chances are it's stemming from some code in your update method. Memory leaks typically occur when you create objects over and over again without destroying the old ones.

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually a memory leak and more an issue of Unbounded memory growth, i'm not creating any objects in my update method. I've noticed the memory creeps up when i jump between most scenes, has anyone else experienced this in spritekit

Comment: Some increase in memory when switching between scenes is normal. Baring a memory leak, you will reach a plateau at some point when memory usage peaks out. Try moving back and forth between scenes 10 to 15 times and see if you level out.

Comment: I'm seeing the memory go from 22MB and if i just jump between the scenes it simply goes up and up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the AGSpriteButton class which was hogging memory and therefore eventually causing a crash when an advert loaded, you can find a fix here:

[SKScene Fails to deallocate memory resulting in bounded memory growth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218195/skscene-fails-to-deallocate-memory-resulting-in-bounded-memory-growth)